# I have a problem with cyberghost in linux 22520

Tags: python, vpn

I try using the program to connect to a server but I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 762, in <module>
  File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 742, in main
  File "servers/traffic.py", line 180, in showInstances
  File "servers/traffic.py", line 89, in getInstances
  File "libs/services.py", line 73, in getServers
  File "libs/api.py", line 195, in doGet
  File "libs/api.py", line 291, in __doRequest
  File "requests/models.py", line 897, in json
  File "simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
  File "simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
  File "simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[22520] Failed to execute script 'cyberghostvpn' due to unhandled exception
```

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; nor what program create the error message (ie. context).  Details in the title need to also exist in your question text (*some browsers/users won't see the title when reading your question*)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Silly question, but have you checked whatever JSON file the program needs for errors? If the JSON file is valid, could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using. This will make it more likely that you receive an answer to your question.